# Out Of Memory while decoding input stream from large image URL

Tags: android, url, bitmap, out-of-memory, decode

Let me describe my current situation:

When somebody uses very large Web images in their new items (that are used in Recycler), this code produces OOM:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String previewUrl, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws Exception {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; // Decode with inJustDecodeBounds to check dimensions
    URL url = new URL(previewUrl);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), null, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; // Decode bitmap with appropriate inSampleSize set

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), null, options);
}
```

I need the result from decodeSampledBitmap() method to compress & save for later use:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));
```

And OOM error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16396 byte allocation with 9344 free bytes and 9KB until OOM
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:645)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:622)
> at com.vsmapp.mainscreen.utils.PreviewImageHandler.decodeSampledBitmap(PreviewImageHandler.java:536)

I used the approach from Android Docs, but still OOM occurs:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#load-bitmap

Maybe I misunderstood something and this is not the best way how to load images:

```
URL url = new URL(previewUrl);
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), null, options);
```

What do you think, guys? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OOM problems aren't just about the immediate code.  It's about all the memory your app is using.  Look for places you can reduce it and things you don't need to keep in memory.  If you're using a recyclerview, a common mistake is to keep the bitmap in the model, rather than keep a file or URI reference where it can be reloaded from.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your comment, unfortunately I work with tablet and I need 20 items to be displayed with the preview web image which can be with any size and that's the problem